# How can I update this function to block out values of NDVI that are greater than or equal to 0.1?

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, filter, masking

Really new to JavaScript and Google Earth Engine, sorry if formatted badly. I am wondering if there is a way to only calculate an NDVI value that is greater than 0.1 in my .addBands line. If not, how would I go about filtering/masking out those values greater than 0.1 (I am just not sure how to write that or where to put it).

```
var addVariables = function(image) {
  // Compute time in fractional years since the epoch.
  var date = image.date();
  var years = date.difference(ee.Date('1970-01-01'), 'year');
  // Return the image with the added bands.
  return image
  // Add an NDVI band.
  .addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI'))
  //only include VALUES greater than 0.1 here?
  // Add a time band.
  .addBands(ee.Image(years).rename('t')).float()
  // Add a constant band.
  .addBands(ee.Image.constant(1));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the NDVI band and then use that same band to mask out values less than 0.1.

```
var addVariables = function(image) {
  // Compute time in fractional years since the epoch.
  var date = image.date();
  var years = date.difference(ee.Date('1970-01-01'), 'year');
  // Calculate ndvi and mask values less than 0.1
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI');
  ndvi = ndvi.updateMask(ndvi.gte(0.1)); 
  // Return the image with the added bands.
  return image
  // Add an NDVI band.
  .addBands(ndvi)
  // Add a time band.
  .addBands(ee.Image(years).rename('t')).float()
  // Add a constant band.
  .addBands(ee.Image.constant(1));
};
```